# How to calculate cutoff freqeuncy of Bandpass filter, given an attenuation dB level (OTHER THAN -3DB)

Tags: filter, band-pass, attenuation

I know that -3dB is the accepted standard, where the power of the signal is at 50%, and that upper and lower cutoff frequencies are calculated with regards to this value, and there are simple formulas for doing so (at -3dB).

However, I would like to calculate such cutoff frequencies for different levels of attenuation (say -1dB, or -2dB) mathematically, without graphing the response.

Thanks for your time and input.

Comment: Consider how the number -3dB is derived... it is not a standard accepted number, nor a magic number. The same way you calculate -3 dB, you can calculate -2 dB or -41 dB.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have an equation for amplitude vs. frequency? You just calculate the frequency at which it achieves the desired fraction of the peak value using algebra. Convert the dB threshold into a normal linear-scaled fraction using:

$$ y = 10^{\text{(threshold in dB)}/10} $$

For -3 dB, this gives 0.5012, approximately 50%.

For -1 dB, you would use 0.7943 and for -2 dB, 0.6310.

The expression might not look at nice when using decimals like these instead of the nice value of \$1/2\$, though.

Comment: Regarding the last remark: the equation will look nice is you *do* use decimals for the -3dB point. -3dB is a rounded number.

Comment: @Huisman - Good point, when we say 3 dB cutoff we really mean exactly 50%, not exactly 3 dB. The rounding is not in 50.12% to 50% as my answer might imply, but in -3.0103 dB to -3 dB.

Comment: 10log is for power, 20log for Voltage transfer function. So x3dB is 0.707 approx. which is half power.